# Laravel: get records from multiple schemas

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, php-extension

I am building a SaaS application that has a set of requirements. One of these requirements is that the application has to be multi-tenant with a seperate schema for every tenant. But there has to be a single instance (admin interface) that needs to access all those schemas for data validation.

Example:
We have x customers who will access their application through customerx.our-company.com. Every customer gets its own schema with multiple tables. These tables contain users, invoices, contracts, timesheets,... The customer has to be able to view/modify these records.

We as a company providing the service have to be able to get all the timesheets from all those customers to be able to verify them. Once verified these records will be updated. `'verified' => true`

My first idea was to store a `tenant_id` in a `customers` table in the admin database to be able to change the database connection in eloquent and merge the records before returning them. This is doable, but I have some questions about performance. What if we grow to 1000+ customers. getting all those records could take a long time.

Dumping all the records in a single schema without providing a separate schema per customer cannot be done because of GDPR. The data of the customer has to be separated.

**What would be the best approach for this design wise? Are there some good articles about this subject?**

What I began to think while writing this question: It is possible to leverage c++, I can create a custom PHP extension that takes multiple tenant database info to get the records via async tasks `std::async`, merge those records and return them. `std::async` creates multiple threads in a pool and I can wait until it is finished. The only big deal will be relations that need to be returned.
Updating those records is a simpler task as we know where it is stored (customer_id) so we can change the DB connection on the fly while updating.

EDIT: I created a simple c++ program that creates async MySQL connections. I've tested this with 10 schemas at once retrieving 1000 records from each. This looks promising, will keep this updated.